# c - Socket error: connection refused

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ubuntu, unix

I'm trying to write a program in C,  I get this error when I try to connect through port 9000 for example or any other port.
It gives me connection refused when i write this:

> ./client hostname-ubuntu 9000
>
> ./client 127.0.0.1 9000
>
> ./client localhost 9000

--> **Server.c code:**

Whats i am doing wrong? Where is the mistake? Help me please.

```
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(int arg,char*argv[]){
int sd,sd_c,port,r;
struct sockaddr_in my_addr, cli_addr;
socklen_t cli_addr_size;
char buf[100];
if (arg!=2){
        fprintf(stderr, "Use:server-port\n");
        return 1;
    }
memset(&my_addr,0,sizeof(my_addr));
my_addr.sin_family=AF_UNIX;
if(1!=sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&port)){
    fprintf(stderr,"Port number must be a number\n");
    return 1;
    }
my_addr.sin_port=htons(port);
my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

sd=socket(PF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,0);
if(-1==bind(sd,(struct sockaddr*)&my_addr,sizeof(my_addr))){
    perror("bind()");
        return 1;
    }
listen(sd,1);
cli_addr_size=sizeof(cli_addr);
sd_c=accept(sd,(struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr,&cli_addr_size);
printf("Client connected from %s:%d\n",inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr),ntohs(cli_addr.sin_port));
close(sd);
while((r=recv(sd_c,buf,100,0))>0){
    write(1,buf,r);
    }
    if(r==-1){
     perror("recv()");
    return 1;
    }
send(sd_c,"xyz",3,0);
close(sd_c);
return 0;
}
```

-->Client.c code

```
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(int arg,char*argv[]){
int sd,r,port;
struct hostent *hh;
struct sockaddr_in adr;
char buf[100];
if (arg!=3){
        fprintf(stderr, "Use : client-address-port\n");
        return 1;
    }
memset(&adr,0,sizeof(adr));
adr.sin_family=AF_INET;
if(1!=sscanf(argv[2],"%d",&port)){
    fprintf(stderr,"Port number is not a number\n");
    return 1;
    }
adr.sin_port=htons(port);
hh=gethostbyname(argv[1]);
if(hh==0||hh->h_addrtype!=AF_INET||hh->h_length<=0){
    fprintf(stderr,"Can't find out server address\n");
    return 1;
    }
memcpy(&adr.sin_addr,hh->h_addr_list[0],4);
sd=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

if(-1==connect(sd,(struct sockaddr*)&adr,sizeof(adr))){
    perror("connect()");
        return 1;
    }
send(sd,"abcd",4,0);
shutdown(sd,SHUT_WR);
while((r=recv(sd,buf,100,0))>0){
    write(1,buf,r);
    }
    if(r==-1){
     perror("recv()");
    return 1;
    }
close(sd);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: My first guess would be to use sudo ./client 127.0.0.1 9000

Comment: Sudo for port above 1024 is not needed... What does the server say, does it accept the connection? Also, the server seems to exit after the first client disconnects...

Comment: command sudo is asking me the password but the keyboard is not working except button "Enter". Again i don't know whats wrong.

Comment: The server is waiting. It just create the socket and it's waiting for a connection

Comment: What does `netstat -an` show?  Do you see your socket listening?

Comment: @Sandu, you should not need to `sudo`, but when you *do* `sudo`, it is intentional and normal that the password you type is not echoed to the screen.

Comment: Possibly your firewall is blocking the connection attempts.  If so, you may find evidence of it in your system logs.

Comment: You don't want your server to be `PF_UNIX` you want `AF_INET`

Comment: When i am writing ./server 9000 It creates me a file on Desktop with name "#(Y�X_ (invalid encoding)"

Comment: @stdunbar THX Dude . Problem SOLVED

Answer (score 1):

You're using two different protocols in your program. AF_INET in your client program and AF_UNIX in the server side. That will never work. Modify these lines of code.

```
my_addr.sin_family=AF_UNIX;
```

to

```
my_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
```

as you used `AF_INET` in the client side;

and

```
sd=socket(PF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,0);
```

to

```
sd=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
```

Hope that helps...